# Legend placement, ggplot, relative to plotting region

Tags: r, ggplot2

Problem here is a bit obvious I think. I'd like the legend placed (locked) in the top left hand corner of the 'plotting region'. Using c(0.1,0.13) etc is not an option for a number of reasons.

Is there a way to change the reference point for the co-ordinates so they are relative to the plotting region?

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c("four","six","eight"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
opts(legend.position = c(0, 1), title="Legend placement makes me sad")
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "plot region"? The region that is filled by grey?

Comment: @kohske Yes, the OP basically wants to be able to determine the correct coordinates for `legend.position` to place the legend in a corner of the "data region", or the grey region. As I mentioned in chat, I suspected someone like you would have to weigh in with a grid solution.

Comment: @joran then, that is the default behavior and all you need is to set correct justification.

Comment: @kohske Whaddya know, I always thought it was based on the device region. Learn something new every day...

Comment: @joran perhaps that was the default behavior before 0.9 or 0.89, I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Update: `opts` has been deprecated. Please use `theme` instead, as described [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193668/4975218)**

The placement of the guide is based on the plot region (i.e., the area filled by grey) by default, but justification is centered.
So you need to set left-top justification:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
  opts(legend.position = c(0, 1), 
       legend.justification = c(0, 1), 
       legend.background = theme_rect(colour = NA, fill = "white"),
       title="Legend placement makes me happy")
```

[image]

If you want to place the guide against the whole device region, you can tweak the gtable output:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
  opts(legend.position = c(0, 1), 
       legend.justification = c(0, 1), 
       legend.background = theme_rect(colour = "black"),
       title="Legend placement makes me happy")

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
nr <- max(gt$layout$b)
nc <- max(gt$layout$r)
gb <- which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")
gt$layout[gb, 1:4] <- c(1, 1, nr, nc)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's not 'hard top left' but being equi distant from both 'edges' will do :)

Comment: opts has been deprecated. Use theme instead.

Comment: This produces an error: 'could not find function "opts"'.

Answer (score 75):

**Update: `opts` has been deprecated. Please use `theme` instead, as described [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193668/4975218)**

Just to expand on kohske's answer, so it's bit more comprehensive for the next person to stumble upon it.

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c("four","six","eight"))
library(gridExtra)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
opts(legend.justification = c(0, 1), legend.position = c(0, 1), title="Legend is top left")
b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
opts(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0), title="Legend is bottom right")
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
opts(legend.justification = c(0, 0), legend.position = c(0, 0), title="Legend is bottom left")
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
opts(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1), title="Legend is top right")

grid.arrange(a,b,c,d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 72):

I have been looking for similar answer. But found that `opts` function is no longer part of ggplot2 package. After searching for some more time, I found that one can use `theme` to do similar thing as opts. Therefore editing this thread, so as to minimize others time.

Below is the similar code as written by **nzcoops**.

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c("four","six","eight"))
library(gridExtra)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + labs(title = "Legend is top left") + 
theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1), legend.position = c(0, 1))

b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + labs(title = "Legend is bottom right") +
theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), legend.position = c(1, 0))

c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + labs(title = "Legend is bottom left") +
theme(legend.justification = c(0, 0), legend.position = c(0, 0))

d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + labs(title = "Legend is top right") +
theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1))

grid.arrange(a,b,c,d)
```

This code will give exactly similar plot.

Answer (score 22):

To expand on the excellend answers above, if you want to add padding between the legend and the outside of the box, use `legend.box.margin`:

```
# Positions legend at the bottom right, with 50 padding
# between the legend and the outside of the graph.
theme(legend.justification = c(1, 0), 
    legend.position = c(1, 0),
    legend.box.margin=margin(c(50,50,50,50)))
```

This works on the latest version of `ggplot2` which is v2.2.1 at the time of writing.

Comment: Nice extension with the margins! Just a tiny suggestion if you want all margins to be the same, use `rep(50, times=4)` for easier adjustment of the margin value